# GCP Data Fusion StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Insufficient 'DISKS_TOTAL_GB' quota. Requested 3000.0, available 2048.0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to deploy a pipeline in GCP Data Fusion. I was initially working on the free account, but upgraded in order to increase quotas as recommended in the following question seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58996991/google-data-fusion-execution-error-invalid-argument-insufficient-disks-total/59038704#59038704).

However, I am still unclear based on the accepted answer as to what specific quota to increase in GCE to enable the pipeline to run. Could someone either provide more clarity in the above linked question or respond here to elaborate on what in the IAM Quotas needs to be increased to resolve the issue seen here:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Insufficient 'DISKS_TOTAL_GB' quota. Requested 3000.0, available 2048.0.
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1123) ~[com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:435) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:900) ~[com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:811) ~[com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:675) ~[com.google.guava.guava-13.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:66) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:518) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:692) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:681) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Insufficient 'DISKS_TOTAL_GB' quota. Requested 3000.0, available 2048.0.
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific quota related to `DISKS_TOTAL_GB` is the `Persistent disk standard (GB)` as you can see in the [Disk quotas documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#disk_quotas).

You can edit this quota by region in the Cloud Console of your project by going to the **IAM & admin page => Quotas** and select only the metric **Persistent Disk Standard (GB)**.

Answer (score 8):

1. Deploy Pipeline.
2. Press "Configure" and choose "Compute config".
3. Press "Customize".
4. Configure "Master Nodes" and "Worker Nodes" setting "Master Disk Size (GB)" and "Worker Disk size (GB)" to use less space.
5. List item

Compute Config
[image: Compute Config]

Answer (score 1):

No need to upgrade from your free trial, Genavs' is the correct answer. Just keep in mind that the lowest value possible is 15GB (it will give you a provisioning error otherwise).
Even with more demanding pipeline than standards, the default 1TB disk size per node is a big no-no. Before tweaking the quotas, always check why you're going above it.